# Tips for Optimizing Oracle Warehouse Builder 11.1 with Oracle DB 10.2

Tags: performance, oracle-10g, data-warehouse, deployment

Are there any tips for improving performance of Control Center and Design Center in Oracle Warehouse Builder? At the client side it is very slow to open and refresh Design center and control center and table/dimension/cube mapping deployments made to a remote database are also slow. Several users (<30) over the network are accessing OWB remote repository and make deployments to remote Oracle 10.2 DB using locally installed Design Center and Control Center.

Please suggest any performance optimization measures at Oracle DB level and at OWB level for the administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that open_cursors is sufficient. What is the current value for open_cursors and session_cached_cursors? They should be high, start with 500.

Comment: Right now the value for open_cursors is 300. Do you think it has to be increased?

Comment: yes, at least 500.

Comment: I kept it at 600 now. Still having same issues. Now TEMP tablespace is overflowing when deployments are happening. Is there a way to optimize the TEMP tablespace usage?

Comment: how is v$open_cursor ? The extent sizes in temp should be right sized, compared to your most used activities. How big are the segments that are kept in TEMP and how big is the extent size fo the TEMP tablespace? If there is a lot of difference you might want to create a separate temp tablespace for the different tasks.

Comment: How do I check the segment size and extent size for TEMP tablespace?

Comment: did you check your open cursors? select a.value, s.username, s.sid, s.serial#
from v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$session s
where a.statistic# = b.statistic#  and s.sid=a.sid
and b.name = 'opened cursors current';

Comment: How is your pga set?

Comment: check dba_tablespaces for extent sizes and other properties of tablespaces.

Comment: Extent size is only 20M. What is the optimal extent size for data warehouse queries which process about 30000 tuples? Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: check AWR. See <http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10822/toc.htm> lots of explaining there.

Comment: That link that you have given seems to be broken.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10822/toc.htm